# Open balls in path connected metric spaces with more than one point

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

Is it true that in every path connected metric space with more than one point, every open ball contains a subset with more than one point which is connected (or possibly more, path connected)? Suppose $B$ is an open ball with center $x$ and let $x \ne y \in B$ (such $y$ exists by [Does there exist a connected metric space, with more than one point and without any isolated point, in which at least one open ball is countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327483/does-there-exist-a-connected-metric-space-with-more-than-one-point-and-without)) and consider $\hat B:=\{y \in B: x,y$ are connected by a path lying in $B\}$ ; then does $\hat B$ has more than one point? Is $B$ connected?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is positive:  in every path connected metric space with more than one point, every open ball contains a path-connected subset with more than one point.

Proof. If $B$ is an open ball and $p\in B$, by assumption there is a nonconstant continuous map $\gamma:[0,1]\to X$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$. If $\gamma([0,1])\subset B$, it is the desired set. Otherwise let $b =\inf\{t: \gamma(t)\notin B\}$. The continuity of $\gamma$ implies  $b>0$. The set $\gamma([0,b))$ is what you want.

---

By the way: for general connected spaces, the answer is negative. For example, the [Knaster–Kuratowski fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan) is a connected metric space $X$ that contains a point $p$ such that $X\setminus \{p\}$ is totally disconnected (has no connected subsets with more than one point). In particular, an open ball that is disjoint from $p$ does not contain any connected subsets with more than one point.

Comment: But does the set $\gamma ([0,b))$ has more than one point ?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise $\gamma$ would be constant on $[0,b)$, and then $\gamma(b)=\gamma(0)\in B$, a contradiction to the choice of $b$.